# Rename function in a specific package on Common Lisp

Tags: import, package, common-lisp

I want to use the package cl-ppcre and series directly on my common lisp environment. I use sly, so in my slynkrc I add this code:

```
(setf (cdr (assoc '*print-length* slynk:*slynk-pprint-bindings*)) 20)
(setf *print-length* 20)
(setf  *evaluator-mode* :interpret)

(ql:quickload '(:alexandria
                :cl-ppcre
                :cl-interpol
                :series
                :cl-actors
                :chanl
                :lparallel))

(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :execute :load-toplevel)
  (series::install))

(defun λ-reader (stream char)
  (declare (ignore char stream))
  'LAMBDA)

(set-macro-character #\λ #'λ-reader)
(use-package :cl-ppcre)
(use-package :cl-interpol)
(interpol:enable-interpol-syntax)
```

The problem with this is whith the symbol function split. that is in both packages defined.

```
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10005605B3}>:
  USE-PACKAGE #<PACKAGE "CL-PPCRE"> causes name-conflicts in
  #<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER"> between the following symbols:
    CL-PPCRE:SPLIT, SERIES:SPLIT
```

See also:

In Scala you can import, [Renaming a class](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-how-to-rename-class-import-importing-syntax-examples), but in this case I can use shadowing import, and import only what I need, what is the best solution for that, and if it is possible to import and rename a function in common lisp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could maybe do it like this:

```
(defun alias% (as symbol &key (package *package*))
  (when (fboundp symbol)
    (setf (symbol-function as) (symbol-function symbol)))
  (when (boundp symbol)
    (setf (symbol-value as) (symbol-value symbol)))
  (setf (symbol-plist as) (symbol-plist symbol))
  ;; maybe also documentation of all types
  (shadowing-import as package))

(defmacro defalias (as symbol &key (package *package*))
  `(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
     (alias% ',as ',symbol :package ,package)))
```

Then you can do:

```
(defalias foo cl:list)

(foo 1 2 3)   ; => (1 2 3)
```

Comment: Sorry, could you provide an example of usage I always get the error or unbound variable or is not type string when using defalias

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [the doc on CLtL2](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node116.html#NAMECONFLICTSSECTION), I'd say there is no macro to do that. Please prove me wrong.

Maybe the following works ? *I didn't test properly* **edit: it doesn't work as is**.

```
(use-package :cl-ppcre)
(setf (fdefinition 're-split) #'split)  ;; create an alias
(unintern 'split)
(use-package :series)
```

And now use `re-split` and `split`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, The packages that conflicts are series and cl-ppcre with the split function. that code did not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to "rename" functions, you could create a macro that defines a function that just applies the other function, which is really simple to write:

```
(defmacro defalias (name actual)
  `(defun ,name (&rest rest)
     (apply #',actual rest)))
```

This is not exactly an alias because it creates an actual function which happens to delegate to another. Anyway, could be useful.

Example usage:

```
(defalias str-prefix-p uiop:string-prefix-p)

(str-prefix-p "a" "abc") ;; T
(str-prefix-p "b" "abc") ;; NIL
```